# jquery modal submit button to replace window data

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

i have a jquery modal setup that appears when user clicks submit on form.  this window is a confirmation window of all the data entered in form.  I have 2 buttons, Go and cancel.  when the user clicks cancel, it goes back to form, and they can re-submit or do whatever.  when the user clicks Go, the data is passed to the form action value, in this case "complete.php".  What i am looking to do is have the modal submit fire off an ajax that will do all the stuff complete.php, and then return the results in the same modal window we are in...

http://jsfiddle.net/UMenY/1/

```
 <form name='myForm' id='myForm' action='#' method='POST'>
  <input type='text' name='firstName' id='firstName'>
  <input type='button' value='submit' id='subButton'>
</form>
 <div id='dialog'>
 <p id='firstName'></p>
 </div>
 </div>


    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Go": function () {
                document.myForm.submit();
            },
                "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
    });
    $('#subButton').click(function () {
        $("p#firstName").html($('#firstName').val());
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

In this quick little jsfiddle i made, I would like to submit the modal value form input to complete.php via ajax, and have the modal window show "whomever was added to db" if complete cameback successful.

I can not figure out how to add the .submit(function(){  on the submit action.  the only thing i can do is have the form action results, and take me to a new page, which i dont want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind the submit callback to your form in the [open event](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-open).

```
        open: function(event, ui){
            $(this).parents('form:first').submit(function(){});
        }
```

Added updated JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mac1175/Hwqjk/

### JS

```
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 800,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        buttons: {
            "Go": function () {
                $('#myForm').trigger('submit');
            },
                "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $('#myForm').submit(function (e) {
                console.log('do ajax call here');
                e.preventDefault();

                return false;

            });
            console.log('fomr bound');
        }
    });
    $('#subButton').click(function () {
        $("p#firstName").html($('#firstName').val());
        $('#dialog').dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: actually what i did was i preformed the ajax call on the button Go attribute

http://jsfiddle.net/UMenY/12/